# Array is Updating with useEffect but Always Get the Initial Value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

*This question has been asked many times but none of the solutions have worked for me. I miss something and I need your help to find it out.*
I also provide the whole code to give you context.

---

I have a TV app that shows the production of a factory.

Initially I request the server to check if statically defined lines are working right now.

```
let lineIds = ["3", "1", "9"]
TvApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://192.168.1.10:8090/api/tv_app_checkline/:${lineIds}`)
    const workingLinesResponse = await res
    console.log('workingLinesResponse: data: ', workingLinesResponse.data)

    return { workingLines: workingLinesResponse.data }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error getInitialProps:: ', error)
    return { data: null }
  }
}
```

---

In the first `useEffect`, I keep checking every 15 seconds if the lines are still working;
Server responds with the `workingLines`.

In the second `useEffect`, I use `workingLines` to get production data for the currently working lines.

My problem is;

In the first `useEffect`, `setWorkingLines(response.data)` is updating `workingLines` but cannot be used by the second `useEffect`. Second `useEffect` always shows the initial value.

```
export default function TvApp(props) {

  const [workingLines, setWorkingLines] = useState(props.workingLines);
  //first useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const API = `http://192.168.1.10:8090/api/tv_app_checkline/:${lineIds}`

      axios.get(API)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('workingLines initially:: ', response.data)
          setWorkingLines(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, 15000); 
  },[])

  var activeLineId = 0
  //second useEffect    
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {     
      axios.get(`http://192.168.1.10:8090/api/tv_app/:${workingLines[activeLineId]}`)//workingLines is always the initial value, not updated one.
        .then(response => {
          //Set reponse to use in the view.
        })
       
      if (activeLineId === workingLines.length - 1) {
        activeLineId = 0
      } else {
        activeLineId = activeLineId + 1
      }

      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, 10000);
  }, []); //using workingLines as a dependency is causing the multiple api requests

}
```

If I use `workingLines` as a dependency in the second `useEffect`, the api request is calling multiple times.

I can check the `workingLines` with following `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('workingLines:: ', workingLines) //this shows that, workingLines is successfully updated by the first useEffect
}, [workingLines])
```

How can I use the updated `workingLines` in the second `useEffect` without calling the api multiple times?

Comment: If I may ask, why you're using `getInitialProps ` at all? Why don't you just use two `useEffect`(s) you already have?

Comment: Good point. I'm new to `ReactJS` and without the `getInitialProps`, I always get the `no data found` error. Possibly, I cannot successfully check the data if exist in first render.

Comment: Can you put your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can check it out? I have some ideas, but I would really like to see the whole thing first.

Comment: Checking working lines is new feature and render function is not reflecting the above question. That's why whole code is useless right now. Also, can we make api calls on `codesandbox`? But if you can check the previous version of the app, I can post to `codesandbox`.

Comment: We can make API calls on codesandbox, but we can also fake the data for the sake of searching for a bug in your logic. That's why I asked for the code. :)

Comment: I was not manipulating the array in previous version of the app. Above `useEffect`s are not exist in the whole code. Whole code only could help for the `getInitialProps`. Otherwise, using the updated array issue is already presented in the question. I created `codesandbox` for the above question: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-i2l2w?file=/demo.js

Comment: Sorry but the code doesn't contain the one you posted in the original question.